# VPN limitation and questions

Tags: windows, vpn, file-sharing

I have a computer (I'll call it 'A') that connects to internet but is unable to host websites, since ISP blocks those ports and I don't have access to router to do port forwarding.

I bought a VPS and run a website there call it 'B'. I want to create a VPN network between A and B. How do I do that? B is a Windows Server and I assume all port is opened since it is VPS.

Question:

1. However A is behind a router that blocks most incoming ports, can A (client) connect to B (server) and both able to share files to each other?
2. How do I set up a VPN connection between the Windows Server 2003 (server) and Windows 7 (client)?

Answer (score 0):

> However A is behind a router that block most incoming ports, can A (Client) connect to B (VPN Server) and both able to share files to
>   each other?

Answer: Definite Maybe.  As long as you are SURE that ONLY the incoming ports are being blocked, an outgoing request shouldn't be prevented.

> Can give me guide to setup VPN server in windows server 2003 3. Can give me a guide to setup VPN client with windows 7 to connect to VPN
>   server?

Answer:  Yes and yes.  But before I do that, can I ask, is the VPS what you are planning on using as your VPN server?  Is your hosting service aware of this?  If they are, don't they have a guide for you to use?

Comment: hi Everett thanks for answering but I am still confuse. If Client is blocked from incoming port, how do server able to initiate communication with client to retrieve data from client side?

Comment: The server is not initiating communication, the client is.  The router (the one you reference in the first question) has been told to only block incoming initiation requests (going into the network where the client is asking a service to build a connection), not incoming responses (the request to build the connection exited from the network the client is in through the router, to a server running a service outside the network, and it is responding).  VPN servers don't request connections, clients do.